# Creating a Stripe Customer Through a Cloud Function

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to register a customer through Firebase Realtime-Database, but I'm needing help adding a stripeID to the customer reference through a Cloud Function. I can register a customer just fine, but how can I append my Cloud Function when I click the sign up action because I'm not getting anything in the Firebase Function Logs right now? Thank you.

**Cloud Function**

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

    const email = data.email
    const uid = context.auth.uid
    console.log(uid)

    if (uid === null) {
      console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt')
    }

    return stripe.customers
    .create({ email: email })
    .then((customer) => {
      return customer["id"];
    })
    .then((customerId) => {
      admin.database().ref("customers").child(uid).update({
        stripeId: customerId,
        email: email,
        id: uid
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "internal",
        " Unable to create Stripe user : " + err
      );
    });

})
```

**WelcomeActivity.kt**

```
    signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
            val registerStub = findViewById<ViewStub>(R.id.registerStub)
            registerStub.inflate()

            performRegister()

    }

    private fun performRegister() {

        // MARK: - Register ViewStub Properties

        val registerViewStubProfileImageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.addPhotoImageButton)
        val registerViewStubFullnameTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.fullnameInputTextView)
        val registerViewStubUsernameTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.usernameTextInputView)
        val registerViewStubEmailTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.emailInputTextView)
        val registerViewStubPasswordTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.passwordTextInputView)
        val registerViewStubConfirmPasswordTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.confirmPasswordTextInputView)
        val registerViewStubCancelButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.secondCancelButton)
        val registerViewStubSignUpButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.secondSignUpButton)

        val fullnameText = TextUtils.isEmpty(registerViewStubFullnameTextView.text)
        val usernameText = TextUtils.isEmpty(registerViewStubUsernameTextView.text)
        val emailText = TextUtils.isEmpty(registerViewStubEmailTextView.text)
        val passwordText = TextUtils.isEmpty(registerViewStubPasswordTextView.text)
        val confirmPasswordText = TextUtils.isEmpty(registerViewStubConfirmPasswordTextView.text)

        registerViewStubSignUpButton.setOnClickListener {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(registerViewStubEmailTextView.text.toString(), registerViewStubPasswordTextView.text.toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

                    // else if successful
                    uploadImageToFirebaseStorage()

                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create user: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }

    }

    private fun uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {

        if (selectedPhotoUri == null) return

        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/customer_profile_images/$filename")

        ref.putFile(selectedPhotoUri!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    saveCustomerToFirebaseDatabase(it.toString())
                }
            }

    }

    private fun saveCustomerToFirebaseDatabase(profileImageUrl: String) {

        val registerStub = findViewById<ViewStub>(R.id.registerStub)
        val registerViewStubFullnameTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.fullnameInputTextView)
        val registerViewStubUsernameTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.usernameTextInputView)
        val registerViewStubEmailTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.emailInputTextView)

        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/customers/$uid")

        val customer = Customer(uid, registerViewStubFullnameTextView.text.toString(), registerViewStubUsernameTextView.text.toString(),
                                registerViewStubEmailTextView.text.toString(), profileImageUrl)

        ref.setValue(customer)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                uploadStripeCustomer()
                registerStub.alpha = 0f
                finish()
            }

    }

    private fun uploadStripeCustomer(): Task<String> {

        val registerViewStubEmailTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.emailInputTextView)

        val data = hashMapOf(
            "email" to registerViewStubEmailTextView
        )

        return  functions
            .getHttpsCallable("createStripeCustomer")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith { task ->
                val result = task.result?.data as Map<*, *>
                result["createStripeCustomer"] as String
            }

}
```

Comment: Does `console.log(uid)` appear at the log?

Comment: Yes I’m getting the customer uid and everything to work properly, but I just can’t get the Cloud Function to trigger

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine, do you need me to upload my repo for you?

Comment: Hi, have you checked this Firebase doc? https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments